# Raspberry Pi 2 refusing to boot after first few reboots

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

Step 1: Put latest Raspbian image (2015-01-31-raspbian.img) on compatible (according to http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards) Micro SD card

Step 2: Boot Raspberry Pi, ssh into it, expand filesystem, reboot

Step 3: apt-get update/upgrade, rpi-update, reboot

Step 4: Kernel Panic on boot

[image: Kernel Panic]

I'm using a 12W iPad charger that outputs 5.2V and 2.4A. The only things plugged into the Pi are the power supply, the screen and the SD card.

This happened four times, each time after rebooting the Pi a few times. Every time it happens, I have to reflash the SD card. Is my Pi just broken?

**Edit:** After reflashing the SD card for the tenth time and trying the third power supply, I've concluded that the power supply is not the culprit.

**Edit 2:** Turns out it was the card (a Sony Micro SD, if anyone's interested). After trying a spare SanDisk 16 GB Micro SD, which worked flawlessly, I bought a SanDisk 64 GB Micro SD and copied the 16 GB card's content over. One filesystem expansion and several app installations and reboots later, everything's still working. The Sony card itself seems to be in perfect working order, it's just that the Pi refuses to boot with it.

Comment: Are you shutting down properly or just yanking the cord?

Comment: I would assume that `sudo reboot` makes the Pi shut down properly. After the kernel panic, I obviously have to yank the cord.

Comment: `sudo reboot` will make RPi reboot. use `sudo shutdown -h now` for safe shutdown. And after black screen and activity led not lighting any more you can yank the cord.

Comment: Well yes, that's why it's called `reboot`. What I meant was that it shuts the Pi down properly first, as opposed to pulling the power cord.

Answer (score 1):

Its your power supply. I had two model B's so when my 2 came in I used one of their supplies (supply came with a kit) and I have had no problems.

Like you I expanded and rebooted, but then I moved my file system to USB and then did upgrade, dist-upgrade, rpi-update.

So yeah, our setups are different, but the power supply I'm using (and is the appropriate supply) is DC  5v 1500mA (1.5A)

Using the wrong supply could cause random writes to SD and as your panic states, it can't read a block.

I'm not an electrical guy, so I'm not sure if your cord will eventually fry something, but if you have a USB drive you might get away with putting on USB and then do your updates, but really, you should just buy the appropriate supply off Amazon or your site of choice. If you're in the states and still have a radio shack in area, they may have one. One in my area caries pi supplies.

Edit: plus even with the right supply, I would still say put the file system on USB. Better performance (IMO) and you don't have to worry about SD wear and tare.

Edit 2: Not sure if it would even matter, but we're it me, I would probably expand file system and reboot, then rpi-update and reboot, then apt-get (if boots) while trying to troubleshoot this issue, but again, I really think it is your power supply giving you the trouble.

Comment: What power supply would you recommend? I want to use the Pi with a WiFi stick later on, so I figured the iPad charger would be good enough.

Comment: [Link](http://www.amazon.com/Raspberry-Pi-Micro-Supply-Charger/dp/B00DZLSEVI) feel free to shop around. Like I said, if your in the states and in area that still has radioshack, they may have one. Main thing is that it's DC 5v 1500mA (1.5A)

Comment: Tried a few other power supplies and concluded that it's **not** the power supply. Something else is wrong with my Pi and the cryptic error messages on boot are not helping.

Comment: Did any of them match the above mentioned specs?

Comment: One did, the others were either 5V 1A or 5.2V 2.4A ones.

Comment: Could be the card. If you have spare usb drive, move file system to that and then do your upgrades. In this way the sdcard will only get read for a moment at boot and then everything runs off of usb. Check out [This how to](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=44177) or try a different class 10 micro SD. Although I'm just using one from an old android phone. Not sure of brand or class, but it only gets hit once at boot, so not really an issue