# Special configuration steps for RasPi 3?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, pi-3

I have a RasPi 3 on which I'd like to run OSMC. [I have problems to login via `ssh`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/292136/117993); I tried Raspian (on another SD card but the same Pi), and `ssh` won't work there, either (*yes* it is enabled, and WiFi connection works like a charm).

Now I suspect the problem might be caused from an incompability: I think the images were made for RasPi 2, and there have been hardware changes. I executed `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` successfully and rebooted, but this didn't help.  Are there special configuration steps necessary to adjust to RasPi 3?

**Update,** requested information:

```
# uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.4.13-v7+ #894 SMP Mon Jun 13 13:13:27 BST 2016 armv71 GNU/Linux
# cat /etc/debian_version
8.0
# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

The Pi is connected via WiFi (DHCP, talking to a Fritz!Box 7170), which - as far as I'm concerned - works flawlessly, including DNS. I don't have any problems to `ssh` to my Pi 1B which runs OpenElec.

**Please note,** this question is *not* about my `ssh` problem but about special measures for RasPi 3.

Comment: You have provided no information. What version are you running `uname -a` `cat /etc/os-release ` etc? How is your network setup?

Comment: @Milliways: I updated my question providing some information.

Comment: There are no special configuration steps to get SSH functional in Raspberry Pi 3

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure sshd is running?

run `systemctl status sshd` and check that it is

If it's not, one way to enable it is using raspi-config

- run `raspi-config`
- select `advanced options`
- select `ssh`
- select `yes` to enable it

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't make clear enough *this* question is not about my `ssh` problem. If only it would be that easy! If you are interested, [here is my ssh question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/292136/117993).

Comment: If this question isn't about ssh then what is it about?

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is not about my `ssh` problem but about special steps for RasPi 3, I think I found the answer. In [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/27723/12333) I stumbled over the topic `rpi-update`. Thus, for Raspbian, the following steps updated my firmware:

```
# apt-get install rpi-update
# rpi-update
# shutdown -r now
```

Sadly, this didn't solve my `ssh` problem; but that was not the question.